# WSADuplicateSocket error 10024 after signal handling

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, server, signals

I'm writing a server in C (WIN32) using the `pre-forking` model. I have a problem  running the server in process mode (using processes), between signal handling and `WSADuplicateSocket` function

**This is my signal handler:**

```
BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 

    //CTRL_C_EVENT
    if(fdwCtrlType == CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
    {
        printf("break-event\n");
        newConf=1; // 0?no new config:there is new config
        return TRUE;

    }
    else if(fdwCtrlType == CTRL_C_EVENT)
    {
        printf("\nCLOSING SERVER \n");

        return FALSE;

    }
}
```

**This is the structure/pseudoce of my server:** (no error checking or other stuff)

```
int main(...)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE);
    Conf = readConfig("config.txt"); // a struct
    int N= Conf -> N; //number of workrer
    int mod=Conf->mod; //mod-->  1?thread:process
    createWorkers(); //run N worker and store information about them in arrays
    //
    socket init, listen() etc..
    //
    while(1)
    {
        if(newConf==1)
        {
           //read back config.txt
           //change mod,add new worker, delete worker etc..
        }
        socket=accept(); //wait for client
        //choose a worker to send socket

        if(mod == 0)
        WSADuplicateSocket(clientSocket, pidWorker, &protInfo);

        //sendsocket
        ...     

    }


}
```

My problem is that if I try to generate the `CTRL + BREAK` signal with the keyboard while the main Server is waiting for a client to connect, the handler executes correctly, but as soon as a client connects, the `WSADuplicateSocket` function fails with:

```
error code 10024. "Too many open sockets"
```

but I run the program (for simplicity) only with a worker process.
This problem only occurs if I generate the `CTRL + BREAK` signal while the main is waiting on the accept. If I run the program without generating signals, the socket is duplicated correctly, opened correctly by the process that received and used it.

Comment: Unrelated but, don't cast `CtrlHandler`, fix your function declaration. Probably needs `CALLBACK`.

Comment: Seeing just this crippled code, answering would be guessing, which I won't.

Comment: Does it work for Ctrl-C?

Comment: It works for ctrl C

Comment: The rest of the code, or thousands of lines of code, does not matter. The problem occurs only when the ctrl + break signal is handled, while the server is waiting on the accept. That's all. It is the management of the signal that causes this problem, since it does not present itself for any normal reason.

Comment: @Anders the declaration is ok.

Comment: If the declaration is OK then you can remove the pointless cast when you call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: @Anders it's the same.  If I remove the cast I get a warning. Only adding WINAPI in the declaration I can remove the cast

Comment: By the way the problem persist. A single ctrl+break event causes the error 10024 in wsaduplicatesocket

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. What's the action in the condition `newConf==1`, since you set the newConf to 1 in `CtrlHandler()`.