# Are there any other types of console events?

Tags: c, winapi, events, console

I know that in `C WIN32` there are these console-events:

- `CTRL_C_EVENT` - occurs when the user presses CTRL+C, or when it is
  sent by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent API.
- `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` - occurs when the user presses CTRL+BREAK, or when
  it is sent by the GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent API.
- `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` - occurs when attempt is made to close the console,
  when the system sends the close signal to all processes associated
  with a given console.
- `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT` - occurs when the user is logging off. One cannot
  determine, however, which user is logging off.
- `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT` - occurs when the system is being shutdown, and
  is typically sent to services.

Are there any other types of `console-events`?
I need to send a `console-event` to a server that once managed, leads the server to reread a configuration file. The event `CTRL + C` is used to close the server.

[To do this I used the `CTRL + BREAK` event, but unfortunately I still could not understand why, it gives me problems with the wsaDuplicateSocket  function (error 10024).](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54362023/694576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer now is no, There is some definitions in consoleapi.h header file:

```
#define CTRL_C_EVENT        0
#define CTRL_BREAK_EVENT    1
#define CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT    2
// 3 is reserved!
// 4 is reserved!
#define CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT   5
#define CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT 6
```

nothing more.